# Binding dropdownlist when adding a new row in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a drop down and some textboxes in a gridview and im binding the DDL from DB values and i have to add a new row with same DDL and textboxes but how can i bind the DDL when a new row is created??

Answer (score 0):

You can add the new row in `GridView` Footer. During `RowDataBound` event you can find the DDL and Bind the data,

```
protected void gv1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        DropDownList ddlName= (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("dlstName");
        // You can bind data to ddlName
    }
}
```

Comment: But how can i bind the DDL everytime a new row is created??

Comment: No, That will not call everytime.. when the Row type is Footer only that portion of the code will execute. Grid have only one Footer, So it will execute only one time. Hope it is clear.